# Change label on a page from another window C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I have made an application with a NavigationWindow with a page loaded in it. Also is another (normal) window in this project.
The names of these windows/pages:

```
NavigationWindows: MainWindows
Page: Page1
Window: TwitterConnect
Label on Page: label4
```

I have a label on my Page1 and I want to change it from TwitterConnect.
Because I make a new instance of Page1 to call method ConnectToTwitter(), the label on my page doesn't update.
Here is the code in de codebehind of TwitterConnect:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {  
            string pin = twitpin.Text;    

            Page1 page = new Page1();

            page.ConnectToTwitter(pin, genratedToken);

            this.Close();     
        }
```

I searched google to find a solution, but I don't get it.
I think it has something to do with Dispatcher?!

I'm really a beginner in C#, VS10express and WPF.

How can I change label4 from TwitterConnect?
Can you please explain it with a snippet of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of *Page1.xaml* from the *TwitterConnect* window. What you need to do is find a way to access the current instance of *Page1.xaml* which can easily be acheived by using the *DataContext* property of the *Window* class.

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TwitterConnect twitterWindow = new TwitterConnect();
    // this gives TwitterConnect access to Page1's label4 property
    twitterWindow.DataContext = this;
    twitterWindow.Show();
}
```

**TwitterConnect.xaml.cs**

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Page1 page1 = (Page1)this.DataContext;

    string pin = twitpin.Text;    
    page1.ConnectToTwitter(pin, genratedToken);
    // Then you can update the label like so:
    page1.Label4.Text = "The text you want to display on the label";
    this.Close();   
}
```

If I've missed anything out please let me know. Also, I strongly advise against this configuration as it could become a nightmare to maintain. A better approach might be to add a method or property onto *Page1.cs* to handle setting the text on *label4*.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you need to refresh the control.

> this is a new class

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
 private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };

 public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
 {
  uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
 }
}
```

> this is example method in your class
>   (page1?)

```
private void LoopingMethod()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  label1.Content = i.ToString();
  label1.Refresh();
  Thread.Sleep(500);
}
}
```

please check this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/08/25/refresh--update-wpf-controls.aspx)